# Text without some tokens ANTLR

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have a problem with matching text in my lexer using ANTLR.
I have html-like tags and attributes in this tags. For example:

```
<tag name=" some text {! ... } some text {! ... } some text ">
```

Everything that within attribute value (inside `" ... "`) and outside open brace with exclamation mark (`{!`) and close brace (`}`) is text(`ATTR_TEXT`).
I was trying to do like this, but it doesn't work as I expect, because when lexer finds one of the negated symbols, it splits text into two or more ATTR_TEXT tokens, depending on number of founded negated symbols:

```
...
OPEN            :   '<'                 ->pushMode(INSIDE);
...
mode INSIDE;    

DQUOTE          :   '"'                 ->pushMode(INSIDE_DOUBLE_QUOTES);
...

mode INSIDE_DOUBLE_QUOTES;
OPEN_EXPR   :   '{!'                ->pushMode(INSIDE_EXPR);    
ATTR_TEXT   :   ~["{!}]+ ;
CLOSE_QUOTE :   '"'                 ->popMode;

mode INSIDE_EXPR;

CLOSE_EXPR  :   '}'                 ->popMode;
...
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: But what is your question actually? Please try to formulate your question in a way that matches SO's Q&A style.

Comment: @MikeLischke Thank you! I have edited my question.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you want to get only one `ATTR_TEXT` token which represents non-contiguous text? In that case you'd have to filter the lexer output to glue these tokens together. Out of the box, you'll only get tokens for contiguous text from the lexer.